# gRPC/Protobuf linker errors with MinGW

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I tried to link a program with the `mingw-w64-x86_64-grpc` package(and dependencies) installed to MSYS2.

```cpp
g++ [...sources...] -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc`  -std=c++14
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>::Get(int) const'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>::Set(int, double const&)'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>::Set(int, double const&)'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>::Add()'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>::SwapElements(int, int)'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>::Get(int) const'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>::Get(int) const'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<unsigned int>::Get(int) const'
[..object.o..]: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::RepeatedField<double>::Set(int, double const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:58: build_program] Error 1
```

I tried compiling the grpc v1.30.1 from source and install it, but it seemingly had no effect on the system, and it's another question altogether.

What I'd like to know: **what is missing from the system?**

The code is successfully compiling on a linux virtual machine.
MinGW Environment:

```
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-17763 [..pc_name..] 3.1.5-340.x86_64 2020-06-06 09:16 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

Comment: I tried downloading the 32 bit base installer ( instead of the default 64 bit ),  because of suspected possible architecture inconsistencies, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: The sample code is compiling, but its because of the locally available source code. I believe minGW should be able to compile the server based on the packages, without including the source code in a CMAKE process.